# Compiler Directive error in Delphi 2005

Tags: delphi

Iam using Delphi 2005 and i have included a unit to the main unit using compiler directive i.e.{$I sample.pas}  whenever I try to build the main pas file I get the below error . F 1026 File not found and it shows the path where the sample.pas file is available. I tried different options like tried adding the path of the pas file in the project options- search path and also in the tools-options -library path and it doesnt work. I googled it and found a solution which says to do the following:
In the IDE from the main menu, navigate to

“Tools|Options|Environment Options|Compiling and Running” 
    switch “Show Commandline” ON
    AND set sure you have “Verbosity” set to “Diagnostic”.

The problem is Iam using Delphi 2005  and unable to find the “Verbosity” option in Delphi 2005. It would be great if some one can help me

Comment: is sample.pas in the same folder as the unit into which it is included?

Comment: No. It is in a different path. Its a huge project and there is no way that both the files can be in the same path

Comment: Almost nobody uses Delphi 2005, and this bug or limitation is one of the more obscure ones.  If you bought XE, you would get access to Delphi 2007, which would work just fine for you in this and many other important ways. (NO, I don't work for Embarcadero, just trying to be helpful.)

Comment: @Warren No pblm..Thanks for your comments But unfortunately we are using Delphi 2005 and cannot change the version at this point of time

Comment: you need to use a relative path like marjan says?

Comment: @ David Heffernan  Tried using relative path and it was not working

Comment: I find that quite hard to believe. Does it work in the same directory?

Answer (score 0):

In Delphi 2009 it is right under the Show Commandline setting:

**However, unfortunately for you the verbosity option isn't present in D2006, so I guess it was introduced in either 2007 or 2009.**

[image]

Oh, and as far as the include directive goes: if your sample pas isn't in the same folder as the unit in which it is included, you could try adding the path to the $I directive:

```
{$I ..\..\General\sample.pas}
```

Comment: @ Marjan Venema   Unfortunately the solution that you provided doesnt work.

Comment: @Sutherson: sorry to hear that. Can't help you any further I'm afraid. No access to D2005. Actually, just one more suggestion: checking the includes in various dpr's we have, the filename is always enclosed in single quotes... Though I must admit I don't expect much out of this.

Answer (score 0):

Put the file in the same folder as your project units, and change its extension to ".inc" ( not mandatory but I think that by convention directives files are named like this).

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution could be to get the code working in a package and then have the package keep that part of things compiled. I have been able to use include files in other paths with packages, but it is quite tempermental. It can start rejecting them even with packages for reasons I don't know. This is indeed a VERY annoying problem.

You might also look into doing your builds via your own batch files where you can take full control of the command-line settings that are being used.